# Remove white space around axis

Tags: pgfplots, margins

I want my plots to fill the given figure as much as possible but cannot find out how to remove the white space around the axis node. I already set inner and outer separation of both the tikzpicture and the axis to zero but the space still remains.

What I expect is something like this:
[image]

Here is a MWE to create the figure:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{2212}{−}
\usepgfplotslibrary{groupplots,dateplot}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns,shapes.arrows}
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[framed,outer sep=0pt, inner sep=0pt]%
\begin{axis}[%
every axis label/.append style={draw},
inner sep=0pt,
outer sep=0pt,
height=5cm,
width=5cm,
tick align=outside,
tick pos=left,
label style={inner sep=0pt},
tick label style={inner sep=1pt},
xlabel={xaxis},
ylabel={yaxis}
]%
\end{axis}%
\end{tikzpicture}%
\end{document}%
```

Comment: try to remove `tikzpicture` options, i.e. `\begin{tikzpicture}\begin{axis}[ ...]
`

Comment: The reason of the white space around axis is the `framed` option of tikzpicture environment.

Comment: A million thanks, that did the job!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The padding comes from the `framed` option of your `tikzpicture` environment. You can either remove this option or say `inner frame sep=0pt` in order to remove the padding:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{2212}{−}
\usepgfplotslibrary{groupplots,dateplot}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns,shapes.arrows}
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[framed, inner frame sep=0pt]%
\begin{axis}[%
every axis label/.append style={draw},
inner sep=0pt,
outer sep=0pt,
height=5cm,
width=5cm,
tick align=outside,
tick pos=left,
label style={inner sep=0pt},
tick label style={inner sep=1pt},
xlabel={xaxis},
ylabel={yaxis}
]%
\end{axis}%
\end{tikzpicture}%
\end{document}%
```

[image]

Excerpt from the [Ti*k*Z & PGF manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/graphics/pgf/base/doc/pgfmanual.pdf):

[image]

Answer (score 0):

An `axis` has no extra space, but a background frame has - use the option `tight background`

```
\documentclass[border=0cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[background rectangle/.style={draw=red, thick}, framed, tight background]
\begin{axis}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: An empty graph with a red frame]